# username & password is not prompted while accessing the SVN repos. I can directly access the URL

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn

I created users with the `svnadmin` command but when I access the URL for repos using TortoiseSVN it doesn't prompt me for any password. I can however directly access the URL using my web browser.

Also, I cannot actually upload any files from TortoiseSVN because my credentials are not working.

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: May need some more info about your setup and what you have tried/configured so far to better address the problem.

Comment: My svn repos are in /apps. I changed the document root to point to /apps. Also /apps is owned by apache. The issue is i create users with svnadmin command but when i login to the url for repos it doesn't prompt me for any password. I just can see the page.

Comment: @user2676080 You may have granted access to anoymous users which is the default. you will need to remove all access from them. Something like `trac-admin \location\or\project permission remove anonymous TRAC_ADMIN` (WIKI_VIEW, TICKET_VIEW, etc etc). Then if all is configured you will need to login with a user and you will see what you have assigned to that user

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your authentication data on TortoiseSVN:

**TortoiseSVN** `->` **Settings** `->` **Saved Data**:

[image: Clearing Auth Data in TortoiseSVN]

After that, use TortoiseSVN's Repository Browser to browse to the URL. Assuming that the SVN server doesn't allow anonymous access, you should be prompted for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise usernames and passwords are configured in the conf directory of the repository install.

For example if your repositories are installed at `C:\svn\repos` the `conf` directory there has an authz file, a passwd file and a svnserve.conf file.

Set/uncomment the following in the svnserve.conf file

```
password-db = passwd
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
```

and then in the passwd file set a user line as follows

```
testuser1 = password1
```

The authz file is used to associate users to groups.

Restart what you need to but this should allow you to connect via tortoise as long as everything else is configured properly.

Setting up logins via the URL interface is different depending on how you are setup. If you are using hte lightweight version of trac (tracd I believe) with your subversion instance you can use htaccess.

Comment: Actually, I installed the SVN Server on CentOs Linux Server. And the client is on Windows.