# svn not prompting while access svn repo

Tags: authentication, svn

i have installed svn1.9.4(apache subversion) in fedoa 23. follow this [link](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-svn-subversion-server-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).
 After that,  Create and configure SVN repository then, goes to `http://localhost/svn/testrepo` it s not throw username ans password to authenticate to access the repo

Configuration files:

etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf

```
    LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
    LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
    LoadModule dontdothat_module  modules/mod_dontdothat.so

    <Location /svn>
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath /var/www/svn

       # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
       <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
          # Require SSL connection for password protection.
          # SSLRequireSSL

          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Subversion repositories"
          AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
          #AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-access-control
          Require valid-user
       </LimitExcept>
    </Location>
```

var/www/svn/testrepo/conf/svnserve.conf

```
[general]

 anon-access = none
 auth-access = write
 password-db = passwd
 authz-db = authz
 realm = testrepo
```

var/www/svn/gworksrepo/conf/passwd

```
[users]
 user1 = password1
 user2 = password2
```

Note: i refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473545/username-password-is-not-prompted-while-accessing-the-svn-repos-i-can-directl), but still i have same issue

Suggest me Whats Wrong in my Configuration and how to fix this